# Select duplicates based on two colums in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this file:

```
Animal   birth
a     2015-09-25
a         NA
b     2015-08-26
b     2015-08-26
e     2015-10-18  
e        NA
d     2015-06-15
d     2015-06-15
```

and I need the animals and births identical like this:

```
Animal   birth
b     2015-08-26
b     2015-08-26
d     2015-06-15
d     2015-06-15
```

I tried this code:

```
new.dt= dt[(duplicated(dt$Animal) | duplicated(dt$Animal, fromLast = TRUE)) & (duplicated(dt$birth) & !is.na(dt$birth) | duplicated(dt$birth, fromLast = TRUE) & !is.na(dt$birth)), ]
```

and I got this:

```
Animal   birth
    a     2015-09-25
    b     2015-08-26
    b     2015-08-26
    e     2015-10-18  
    d     2015-06-15
    d     2015-06-15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'Animal', 'birth' and `filter` the groups having more than 1 element

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
    na.omit %>% 
    group_by(Animal, birth) %>% 
    filter(n() >1)
```

Comment: You are the best..
=)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach works if you use `duplicated` with the full data frame. If you had other columns you want to ignore you can just use `dt[, c('Animal', 'birth')]` inside `duplicated`

```
dt[duplicated(dt) | duplicated(dt, fromLast = TRUE)]
#    Animal      birth
# 1:      b 2015-08-26
# 2:      b 2015-08-26
# 3:      d 2015-06-15
# 4:      d 2015-06-15
```